# WPF window not opening when launched from FSI

Tags: wpf, f#-interactive

I have a WPF window which opens fine when run as a Windows application.  I am trying to launch it from FS Interactive but it won't open.

I have used the spawn function suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864563/f-display-a-wpf-window-asynchronously):

```
> val ui : Lazy<System.Windows.Application * System.Threading.Thread> =
  Value is not created.

> val spawn : f:('a -> 'b) -> x:'a -> 'b
```

...but when I run it using

```
spawn loadWindow ()
```

the FSi window simply returns the Window properties:

```
> val it : Window =
>  System.Windows.Window
>    {ActualHeight = 0.0;
>     ActualWidth = 0.0;
>     AllowDrop = ?;
>     AllowsTransparency = ?;
>     AreAnyTouchesCaptured = ?;
>     AreAnyTouchesCapturedWithin = false;
```

The following is the code which works fine when run as an application:

```
let loadWindow() =
   let window = MainWindow2()
   grid3()  |> window.MyStack.Children.Add |> ignore
   window.Root


[<STAThread>]
(new Application()).Run(loadWindow()) |> ignore
```

I have referenced the following from FSi:

```
#r "System.Xaml.dll"
#r "UIAutomationTypes.dll"
#r "WindowsBase.dll"
#r "PresentationFramework.dll"
#r "PresentationCore.dll"
#r "C:\VS Projects\Numerics\packages\FSharpx.TypeProviders.Xaml.1.8.41\lib\40\FSharpx.TypeProviders.Xaml.dll"
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open FSharpx
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've realised my mistake.

I just needed a   `win.Show()`  before returning the window.  The `Application.Run()` does this , but calling from the spawn function doesn't.

Comment: can you show the final working code? I'd really like to see this